# JQuery slide effect with speed instead of duration

Tags: jquery

I tried to slideUp every div with the same speed (not duration), so that a bigger div takes more time than a smaller one.

But as you can see here (http://jsfiddle.net/4AdRH/11/) the small one (100px) slides up faster then the bigger one for the last 100px.

**JS:**

```
var msPerPixel = 4;
$('#div1').slideUp($('#div1').height() * msPerPixel);
$('#div2').slideUp($('#div2').height() * msPerPixel);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I know, that normally duration will be used. But I don't want to do that. I want all slides to have the same speed. That means a bigger container will take more time, than a smaller one - at same speed.

Comment: your fiddle seems to already do what you want. What is the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to show that better. In the fiddle it seems that the small div slides faster, that the bigger div at the last 100px. That would mean, it is not the same speed.

Comment: I think they are sliding the same speed but the easing is what you don't like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, possibly the easing is making it appear to not slide up at the same speed. Try specifying `linear` http://jsfiddle.net/evilbuck/4AdRH/12/

```
var msPerPixel = 4;
$('#div1').slideUp($('#div1').height() * msPerPixel, 'linear');
$('#div2').slideUp($('#div2').height() * msPerPixel, 'linear');
```